# Azure functions fails to bind Ilogger

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions, asp.net-core-3.1

I've already seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48453482/azure-function-fails-to-bind-ilogger) and many similar others, but I checked the dll versions, and they are all at 3.1.0 (.Net CORE 3.1.0), so I don't know why the ILogger logger parameter is not bound in my Azure Functions application.

The error is the usual:

> The 'Users_POST' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:
>   Error indexing method 'Users_POST'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:
>   Cannot bind parameter 'logger' to type ILogger. Make sure the
>   parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding
>   extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure
>   you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your
>   startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(),
>   builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

Comment: I could investigate more this problem: it looks that everythign depends on the situation I describe in the new StackOverflow question I just created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59291143/simply-adding-entityframeworkcore-to-a-basic-azure-function-application-goes-in

Comment: Hi, can you show the .csproj file that you are using now?