# F# errors with ILogger in Azure Functions v2

Tags: azure, f#, azure-functions, ilogger

I have a quite big project with Azure Function v2 written in F#. I create a library in C# where in the constructor I can pass a `ILogger log`. If only I add this library in the Azure Function project, every function returns an error.

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'log' to type ILogger. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding

[image]

In F# I tried to add

```
[<FunctionName("organization")>]
let public organization
    ( [<HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "organisations/{organisationId}")>]
        request : HttpRequestMessage,
        organisationId : string,
        executionContext : ExecutionContext,
        log : ILogger) =

      let PaymentGateway = PaymentGateway(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable "Api_Secret_Key", log)

      ...
```

I saw some posts for example on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3854) or another [post](https://zimmergren.net/after-upgrading-azure-functions-to-v3-and-you-get-cannot-bind-parameter-log-to-type-ilogger-make-sure-the-parameter-type-is-supported-by-the-binding-and-how-you-can-fix-it/) where other people have the same issue. Apparently, the solution is to update the Azure Function from v2 to v3 but I can't do that in my case right now.

Is there any solution?

### Update

The `.fsproj` is

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="FSharp.Core" Version="4.6.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it will make a difference but I don't use commas to separate parameters in my function e.g. let myfunction ([<HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)>]req: HttpRequest) (log: ILogger)

Comment: This is working in my application. The problem is in the `ILogger`

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48453482/azure-function-fails-to-bind-ilogger ?

Comment: The legacy before iLogger was log : TraceWriter - maybe try that...

Comment: Can you show the .fsproj file of your function app?

Comment: I have post an answer, please have a try and let me know whether you can solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a solid week of tests and changes, I found a non-ideal solution but it is working.

In the function I define *logInfo* like that:

```
let logInfo : Action<string> = new Action<string>(fun (x: string) -> log.LogInformation(x))
```

In my C# library, I removed any reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` and I replace it with:

```
private Action<string> _logger;
public PaymentGateway(string apiKey, Action<string> logger) {
    _logger = logger;
}
```

At least, I have logs in my component. I don't like this solution but it is what I can do with F#.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what, your fs is indeed problematic. I posted here the file and code of function that can be triggered successfully:

This is the structure of my function app:

[image]

This is my .fsproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="HttpTrigger.fs" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And this is my trigger file HttpTrigger.fs:

```
namespace Company.Function

open System
open System.IO
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
open Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs
open Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
open Newtonsoft.Json
open Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

module HttpTrigger =
    // Define a nullable container to deserialize into.
    [<AllowNullLiteral>]
    type NameContainer() =
        member val Name = "" with get, set

    // For convenience, it's better to have a central place for the literal.
    [<Literal>]
    let Name = "name"

    [<FunctionName("HttpTrigger")>]
    let run ([<HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)>]req: HttpRequest) (log: ILogger) =
        async {
            log.LogInformation("F# HTTP trigger function processed a request.")

            let nameOpt = 
                if req.Query.ContainsKey(Name) then
                    Some(req.Query.[Name].[0])
                else
                    None

            use stream = new StreamReader(req.Body)
            let! reqBody = stream.ReadToEndAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask

            let data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NameContainer>(reqBody)

            let name =
                match nameOpt with
                | Some n -> n
                | None ->
                   match data with
                   | null -> ""
                   | nc -> nc.Name
            
            let responseMessage =             
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) then
                    "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                else
                    "Hello, " +  name + ". This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."

            return OkObjectResult(responseMessage) :> IActionResult
        } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

Works fine, successful log:

[image]

These is my step to create and run F# function:

1.Run these two command in cmd:

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ItemTemplates

dotnet new --install Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ProjectTemplates
```

2.Create function app:

```
dotnet new func --language F# --name FunctionsInFSharp
```

3.Create trigger:

```
dotnet new http --language F# --name HttpTrigger
```

4.Add trigger to compile:

```
<Compile Include="HttpTrigger.fs" />
```

Please add above code to ItemGroup in .fsproj file.

5.Change the template, change these from none to Content:

[image]

All I have given is a simple example of how the F# function can be triggered successfully, please try it and let me know whether you can solve it.:)

Comment: Thank you for that. My problem is when I have to pass the `log` to another function. In my code `PaymentGateway` receives `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`. The only reference to the `PaymentGateway` with the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` breaks all Azure Functions

Comment: @Enrico Can you provide more details? This error is a common error. Most of the time, it is caused by inconsistent assembly versions.

Comment: @Enrico The function package itself will bring a lot of assemblies, please first consider the problem of assembly conflicts. Then I want to ask why there is no reference in your .fsproj file?